# Twitter Fabric.io app upload is slow

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric

This is more a devops questions - so I hope it's still good for this forum.

The Fabric Mac app from Twitter Fabric.io upload seems to be really slow.
Whenever I try to upload an app - even one as small as 1MB - it takes 5 minutes to upload - and then it kills all my bandwidth.

Has anyone else had this issue?
It's been like this for a few months - but when I first started using Crashlytics Beta it was a super fast IPA upload.

[image]

Comment: Please let us know if there is any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've also had this issue. I actually ended up switching to Test Flight recently, which although initial upload is reasonably fast, it takes a while for Apple to process the app so it ends up taking about the same amount of time (although it is a lot easier to add collaborators.)

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here, I haven't seen this issue locally, but there are a couple of things you can try.

1) Quit Fabric.app and remove the local cache:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac
```

2) Try submitting via the command line and see if you experience the same behaviour:

```
/path/to/Crashlytics.framework/submit <API_KEY> <BUILD_SECRET> \
-ipaPath /path/to/my.ipa -emails TestEmail@fabric.io,AmazingTester@twitter.com \
-notesPath ~/Notes/ReleaseNotes.txt \
-groupAliases GroupAlias,GroupAlias2 \
-notifications YES
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, I have tried the first suggestion but it has made no difference. Will try the second suggestion next time.

Comment: I'm on Version 2.5.2 (1185) - how do I upgrade to latest version?

Comment: That sounds like the version of Fabric.app ; you'll want to update Crashlytics, by clicking on "Crashlytics" within Fabric.app for the app you're working on and then "Update" or "Install" to pull in the latest version.

Comment: I have Crashlytics 3.7.3 installed - looks like it's already the latest. Am I the only person with this problem? I feel like it should trouble more people at Fabric to know there are developers having issues with this. @doctorBroctor just announced he ditched Fabric for TestFlight because of this issue. I would take that as a very strong call to action.

Comment: Given that @doctorBroctor also experienced, you're not alone in this, but we haven't had a case where we can reproduce this. The next step for me would be to dig into the logs, so if you can send this folder: ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.crashlytics.mac/v3/active zipped up to support(at)fabric(dot)io, that would be great!

Comment: Thanks @Mike Bonnell I forwarded that to you

Comment: any update with this issue? im waiting for 1 hour and it still not uploading it

Comment: I'd double check your network connection and make sure that there are no proxies or firewalls blocking traffic. In general, this is an extremely rare issue.